# Replace all newline not followed by specific

Tags: regex, notepad++

I can easily find '\n' in notepad++, but my problem here is that I have to find '\n' when not followed by a specific character ("#" in this case).
So do I use Regex with '\n'?
Is it possible?

Example :

```
Stuff to ignore
#Like that

Stuff
To change
```

Comment: What version of notepad you have? Check this useful topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try lookahead assersion:

```
\n(?!#)
```

Comment: This will work only in v6.x of Notepad++. earlier versions can't do it.

Comment: I had to do a positive look ahead for mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402043/escaping-asterisk-grabs-wrong-character#43402043

Answer (score 2):

You can find some specifics [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117807/regular-expression-to-match-every-new-line-chraracter-n-inside-a-content-ta), but first make sure your line-endings are purely `\n`.

Mac OS line-endings are `\r` (OSX is `\n`), Windows/DOS are `\r\n`,and UNIX-style are `\n`, mostly.

The regex you are looking for is probably `.*\n[^#].*`, specifying `[^...]` (not set)

But you could try using the EOL regex character, `$`, instead:
    `.*$[^#].*`

Or, as [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) said, just try `\n(?!#)`